# please help in compiling this program

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void *WriteNumbers(void *threadArg)
{
 int start, stop;
 start = atoi((char *)threadArg);
 stop = start + 10;

 while(start<stop)
 {
  printf("%d\n", start++);
  sleep(1);
 }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 pthread_t thread1, thread2;

 // create the threads and start the printing 
 pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, WriteNumbers, (void *)argv[1] );
 pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, WriteNumbers, (void *)argv[2]);

 pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
 pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

 return 0;
}
```

---

```
gcc -o pthread pthread.c 
/tmp/cckJD3rd.o: In function `main':
pthread.c:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
pthread.c:(.text+0xa2): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
pthread.c:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
pthread.c:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere?

Comment: I do not see the question either, you need to be more specific on what you are wanting or this will get deleted.

Comment: sorry...my question is "Please help me in compling above program"

Comment: You need help with linking, not compiling

Answer (score 8):

You need to add the -pthread flag to your compiler.

Comment: Add it to your `makefile` or `gcc` statement.

Comment: Are you using an IDE like eclipse to build your program?

Comment: It's `-lpthread`, not `-pthread`. I know it was likely a careless mistake, but still, why is everyone upvoting this one?

Comment: @Jefromi: From the man page of gcc: Add support for multithreading using the POSIX threads library.  This option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker.  It does not affect the thread safety of object code produced by the compiler or that of libraries supplied with it.

Answer (score 5):

You've not included the pthread library. Try adding

```
-lpthread
```

to your compliation line.

Answer (score 1):

You're not linking with libpthread. And manually compiling with gcc is really BFI. Put your code in a file called 'thread_test.c', and then do:

make thread_test LDFLAGS=-lpthread

Assuming no errors in your code (I didn't check), this should fix your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Add -pthread to gcc cmd line.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
   gcc -o pthread pthread.c  -lpthread
```